# React Native: Image uri doesn't load (only in iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, azure-blob-storage

I have a react-native app that show images from azure, using a uri with a sas token (sample: `https://blob.core.windows.net/folder/image.jpg?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=4vwu%2F6qyPg%2FwAo2EVo7eftiwHcTXPaqNExahhP%2BEM5U%3D&se=2021-01-30T15%3A36%3A00Z&sp=rcw`).

```
              <ImageBackground
                style={{height: 150, width: 220}}
                source={{
                  uri: 'https://blob.core.windows.net/folder/image.jpg?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=4vwu%2F6qyPg%2FwAo2EVo7eftiwHcTXPaqNExahhP%2BEM5U%3D&se=2021-01-30T15%3A36%3A00Z&sp=rcw'
                }}>
                ...
              </ImageBackground>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

On iOS, sometimes images are loaded and sometimes not. On Android all images are loaded corretly every time.

The images that aren't loaded, have the character '%' in the token and iOS replaces it with '%25' making the uri invalid.

Any suggestions for iOS to not encode the '%' in the uri?

Comment: First, try to see what error is. You can try using the prop `onError`. 
`onError={(error) => console.log(error)}`

Comment: @ErickMaeda I have this error:
`{"error": "Failed to load https://blob.core.windows.net/folder/image.jpg?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=4vwu%252F6qyPg%252FwAo2EVo7eftiwHcTXPaqNExahhP%252BEM5U%253D&se=2021-01-30T15%253A36%253A00Z&sp=rcw", "target": 5045}`